# Finding What Object Is In The Array (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5.5

So here's what I'm trying to do in pseudocode:

```
array = new Array();
thisObj = new objectTypeOne();
thisObj2 = new objectTypeTwo();
array.push(thisObj);
array.push(thisObj2);

for( i=0; i<=array.length, i++)
{ 
  if( array[i] == objectTypeOne() )
  {
    //do code
  }
 }
```

I know I could have two different arrays for each object type but that would ruin a lot of my other code which assumes they're both in the same array. (they are pratically same object with slight but vital differences, I suppose I should really have objectTypeTwo derive from other, but that's irrelevant at the moment).

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly do you want to do? You need to find what object type is current object when you loop through array? You can use `if (array[i] is objectTypeOne)` //code

Comment: See the last comment I made to you on my answer. It means you have an undefined reference pushed into your array... which shouldn't happen but you can account for these things with a little error checking to deal with them at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
if(array[i] is MyObjectType) {
   //I found an instance of MyObjectType
}
```

The operator "[is](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is)" does runtime type analysis and will return true if the object you are testing (in this example, `array[i]`) is either directly of the type you're comparing to or a subclass (in this example, `MyObjectType`). You might also want to investigate using [typeof](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#typeof). However, try to avoid having a TON of calls like this or calls using "typeof"... looking up type information at runtime is costly in any language.

Comment: P.S. - I can see you're still pretty new so welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer (and thank you, I'm loving StackOverflow so far).

I just have one error:

Comment: If I use:

if(array[i] is Object())

It says: Incorrect Arguments, Expected one.

If I use:

if(array[i] is Object)

It gives error "term is undefined and has no properties" at runtime

Comment: That's weird.... unless you have a reference in the array that is undefined, which is possible. Try changing the if statement to if(array[i] != undefined || array[i] is Object).

Comment: Nope still says something is undefined :S

Comment: (ignore last post) that error was to do with something else entirely, thank you very much Ascension.

Answer (score 1):

First correct this `i<=array.length` to `i<array.length`. That is the reason for "term is undefined" error.

The solution suggested by @Ascension Systems can be used when you create the instance of diffrent Classes, like

```
array = new Array();
thisObj = new Student();
thisObj2 = new Employee();
array.push(thisObj);
array.push(thisObj2);
```

then you can check like

```
for( i=0; i<array.length, i++)
{ 
  if( array[i] is Student )
  {
    //do code
  }else if(array[i] is Employee){

  }
}
```

If you are using custom Objects, do like this

```
array = new Array();
thisObj = new Object();
thisObj.type = "type1";
....
....
thisObj2 = new Object();
thisObj2.type = "type2";
...
...
array.push(thisObj);
array.push(thisObj2);

for( i=0; i<array.length, i++)
{ 
  if( array[i].type == "type1" )
  {
    //do code
  }else if( array[i].type == "type2"){

  }
}
```